# How can I disable all views inside the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/my_edit_view"
            android:width="100px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        <View .../>
        <View .../>
        ...
        <View .../>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to disable (setEnable(false)) all elements inside LinearLayout `my_layout` ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Another way is to call setEnabled() on each child (for example if you want to do some extra check on child before disabling)

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    child.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: However this only works for the first level children, if you have nested views it won't work.

Comment: One solution is making a recursive function, passing a ViewGroup as parameter. Check the class for its every children, disabled it if it's a EditText.

Answer (score 141):

this one is recursive for ViewGroups

```
private void disableEnableControls(boolean enable, ViewGroup vg){
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
       View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
       child.setEnabled(enable);
       if (child instanceof ViewGroup){ 
          disableEnableControls(enable, (ViewGroup)child);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good snippet, but scrollviews will still be scrollable, some more code is needed for additional functionality

Comment: Spinners not getting disabled not sure why :(

Comment: ViewPagers also don't get disabled, including views inside it.

Comment: It doesn't work because the implementation of setEnabled() lies on the subclass of the view, in other words it can be implemented differently for different views. So there is no way such approach will work for every view in existence

Answer (score 97):

tutu's answer is on the right track, but his recursion is a little awkward.  I think this is cleaner:

```
private static void setViewAndChildrenEnabled(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            setViewAndChildrenEnabled(child, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. It goes through recursively. The current accepted answer only goes one level deep.

Comment: This is the best answer. This disabled all touches inside the layout. That is what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Actully what work for me is:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

and to undo it:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Comment: This solution would disable all views in the activity.  Doesn't really address the question.  What if the goal is to disable only certain ViewGroups in the activity?

Comment: that's exactly I was looking for, thanks!! But then I can detect if user want to click somewhere?

Comment: best solution if u want to disable/enable only one or set of views use the setEnabled(bool) or if the views are all children of one view loop through all children of this view and disable them all but this solution I think is the best(I mean this answer) thanks Idan

Comment: Interesting but is not correct in this case. The question is about all views in some layout, NOT whole activity

Answer (score 27):

If you're interested in disabling views in a specific ViewGroup then you can use the interesting, perhaps slightly obscure `duplicateParentState`. A view state is a set of boolean attributes such as pressed, enabled, activated, and others. Just use this on each child you want to sync to parent ViewGroup:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Note that it duplicates the entire state and not just the enabled state. This may be what you want! Of course, this approach is best if you're loading layout XML.

Comment: So much easier and more specific than a recursive function, thanks for sharing! I added it to a `@style` of a certain button type and magic happened .

Answer (score 19):

I personally use something like this (vertical tree traversal using recursion)

```
fun ViewGroup.deepForEach(function: View.() -> Unit) {
    this.forEach { child ->
        child.function()
        if (child is ViewGroup) {
            child.deepForEach(function)
        }
    }
}
```

usage :

```
   viewGroup.deepForEach { isEnabled = false }
```

Comment: Is missing the `forEach` method I guess

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS it's an `androidx.core.view` method : https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#foreach_1

Answer (score 14):

If some desperate developer scrolls down here, I have another option to do it. Which also disables scrolling as far as I experimented with it. The idea is to use View element like this one in a RelativeLayout, under all your UI elements.

```
<View
                android:id="@+id/shade"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/primaryShadow"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
```

So it is set to be "gone" before some condition. And then you set it's visibility to VISIBLE when you want to disable your UI. Also you have to implement `OnClickListener` for this View. This `onClickListener` will catch click event and won't pass it to the underlying elements.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, yes I was desperate and found your solution scrolling like crazy :D

Comment: Pretty nice solution, actually I had it in my mind and I was looking for someone else  having the same idea so I'm not a crazy loner ;D

Answer (score 13):

Let's change tütü's code

```
private void disableEnableControls(boolean enable, ViewGroup vg){
for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
   View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
   if (child instanceof ViewGroup){ 
      disableEnableControls(enable, (ViewGroup)child);
   } else {
     child.setEnabled(enable);
   }
 }
}
```

I think, there is no point in just making viewgroup disable. If you want to do it, there is another way I have used for exactly the same purpose. Create view as a sibling of your groupview :

```
<View
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/reservation_second_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#66ffffff"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

and at run-time, make it visible. Note: your groupview's parent layout should be either relative or frame layout. Hope this will help.

Comment: Your code won't disable e.g. Spinner, because Spinner extends ViewGroup

Answer (score 9):

Although not quite the same as *disabling* views within a layout, it is worth mentioning that you can prevent **all** children from receiving touches (without having to recurse the layout hierarchy) by overriding the [ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method:

```
public class InterceptTouchEventFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private boolean interceptTouchEvents;

    // ...

    public void setInterceptTouchEvents(boolean interceptTouchEvents) {
        this.interceptTouchEvents = interceptTouchEvents;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return interceptTouchEvents || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

Then you can prevent children from receiving touch events:

```
InterceptTouchEventFrameLayout layout = (InterceptTouchEventFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setInterceptTouchEvents(true);
```

If you have a click listener set on `layout`, it will still be triggered.

Comment: Love this answer.  Pretty light weight and efficient compared to constantly traversing ViewGroup to disable all children!  To solve the issue with the layout still responding to clicks, you can just disable/enable the layout in setInterceptTouchEvents()

Comment: how about passing context to cinstructor? You cant create view without context

Comment: this is the most efficient workaround for a production app.

Answer (score 9):

### Details

- Android studio 3.1.4
- Kotlin 1.2.70
- checked in minSdkVersion 19

### Solution

```
fun View.forEachChildView(closure: (View) -> Unit) {
    closure(this)
    val groupView = this as? ViewGroup ?: return
    val size = groupView.childCount - 1
    for (i in 0..size) {
        groupView.getChildAt(i).forEachChildView(closure)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
val layout = LinearLayout(context!!)
layout.forEachChildView {  it.isEnabled = false  }

val view = View(context!!)
view.forEachChildView {  it.isEnabled = false  }

val fragment = Fragment.instantiate(context, "fragment_id")
fragment.view?.forEachChildView {  it.isEnabled = false  }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  private void disableLL(ViewGroup layout){
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(false);
        child.setClickable(false);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
            disableLL((ViewGroup) child);
    }
}
```

and call method like this :

```
RelativeLayout rl_root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_root);
disableLL(rl_root);
```

Comment: The recursion is aesthetically pleasing :)

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, you can use `isDuplicateParentStateEnabled = true` before the `View` is added to the `ViewGroup`.

As documented in the `setDuplicateParentStateEnabled` method, if the child view has additional states (like checked state for a checkbox), these won't be affected by the parent.

The xml analogue is `android:duplicateParentState="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

I improved the **tütü** response to properly disable EditText and RadioButton componentes. Besides, I'm sharing a way that I found to change the view visibility and add transparency in the disabled views.

```
private static void disableEnableControls(ViewGroup view, boolean enable){
    for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = view.getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(enable);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup){
            disableEnableControls((ViewGroup)child, enable);
        }
        else if (child instanceof EditText) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) child;
            editText.setEnabled(enable);
            editText.setFocusable(enable);
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(enable);
        }
        else if (child instanceof RadioButton) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) child;
            radioButton.setEnabled(enable);
            radioButton.setFocusable(enable);
            radioButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(enable);
        }
    }
}

public static void setLayoutEnabled(ViewGroup view, boolean enable) {
    disableEnableControls(view, enable);
    view.setEnabled(enable);
    view.setAlpha(enable? 1f: 0.3f);
}

public static void setLayoutEnabled(ViewGroup view, boolean enable, boolean visibility) {
    disableEnableControls(view, enable);
    view.setEnabled(enable);
    view.setAlpha(enable? 1f: 0.3f);
    view.setVisibility(visibility? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty delayed answer.But it might help someone. Many answers mentioned above seem to be good. But if your layout.xml has nested viewgroups. Then above answers may not provide full result. Hence i have posted my opinion as a snippet. With the code below one can disable all views (Including Nested ViewGroups).

**NOTE: Try avoiding nested ViewGroups as they are not recommended.**

```
 private void setEnableView(boolean b) {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_container);
    ArrayList<ViewGroup> arrVg = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) child;
            arrVg.add(vg);
        }
        child.setEnabled(b);
    }

    for (int j=0;j< arrVg.size();j++){
        ViewGroup vg = arrVg.get(j);
        for (int k = 0; k < vg.getChildCount(); k++) {
         vg.getChildAt(k).setEnabled(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can have whichever children that you want to have the same state as the parents include android:duplicateParentState="true".  Then if you disable the parent, whatever children you have that set on will follow suit.
```

This will allow you to dynamically control all states at once from the parent view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/some_parent_something"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:duplicateParentState="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:duplicateParentState="true" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/my_edit_view"
            android:width="100px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:duplicateParentState="true" /> 
        <View .../>
        <View .../>
        ...
           <View .../>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below recursive function to make your child views **visible** or **gone**.
First argument is your parent view and second argument decides if you want childs of parent view visible or gone. **true = visible false = gone**

```
private void layoutElemanlarininGorunumunuDegistir(View view, boolean gorunur_mu_olsun) {
    ViewGroup view_group;
    try {
        view_group = (ViewGroup) view;
        Sabitler.konsolaYazdir(TAG, "View ViewGroup imiş!" + view.getId());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Sabitler.konsolaYazdir(TAG, "View ViewGroup değilmiş!" + view.getId());
        return;
    }

    int view_eleman_sayisi = view_group.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < view_eleman_sayisi; i++) {
        View view_group_eleman = view_group.getChildAt(i);
        if (gorunur_mu_olsun) {
            view_group_eleman.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            view_group_eleman.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        layoutElemanlarininGorunumunuDegistir(view_group_eleman, gorunur_mu_olsun);
    }
}
```

Comment: question was about disabling, not hiding views

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a set of, or say a particular kind of view.Let's say you want to disable a fixed number of buttons with some particular text of or no text 
then you can use array of that type and loop through the array elements while disabling the buttons using setEnabled(false) property You can do it on a function call like this:

```
public void disable(){
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
                if(bt[i].getText().equals("")){//Button Text condition
                    bt[i].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents function without recursion

```
    package io.chord.ui.utils

import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.view.forEach

class ViewUtils
{
    companion object
    {
        fun setViewState(view: View, state: Boolean)
        {
            var depth = 0
            val views: MutableMap<Int, MutableList<View>> = mutableMapOf()
            views[depth] = mutableListOf(view)

            while(true)
            {
                val currentViews = views[depth]
                val nextViews = mutableListOf<View>()

                currentViews!!.forEach { view ->
                    if(view is ViewGroup)
                    {
                        view.forEach { children ->
                            nextViews.add(children)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(nextViews.size == 0)
                {
                    break
                }

                depth++

                views[depth] = nextViews
            }

            views.flatMap {
                it.value
            }.forEach {
                it.isEnabled = state
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to have a control over the root view so I added the `includeSelf` flag to `deepForEach`

```
fun ViewGroup.deepForEach(includeSelf: Boolean = true, function: View.() -> Unit) {
    if (includeSelf) function()
    forEach {
        it.apply {
            function()
            (this as? ViewGroup)?.apply { deepForEach(includeSelf, function) }
        }
    }
}
```

usage :

```
   viewGroup.deepForEach (includeSelf: true) { isEnabled = false }
```

Answer (score -1):

Set

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

for yor ViewGroup view. All descendants will not take focus.

Comment: He's not asking about focus.

Answer (score -1):

For me RelativeLayout or any other layout at the end of the xml file with width and height set to match_parent with attribute focusable and clickable set to true.

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">

        <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

to disable a view, you must call the method setEnabled with false for argument.
ex:

```
Button btn = ...
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is creating a <View in your xml, with match_parent for height and width, make sure the view is above every other views, then when you want to prevent clicks, make it visible add an onClickListener to that view with null as parameter.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/my_edit_view"
            android:width="100px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        
        <View
            android:id="@+id/disable_layout_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your code:

```
val disableLayoutView = rootView.find<View>(R.id.disable_layout_view)
disableLayoutView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
disableLayoutView.setOnClickListener(null)
```