# Get the View of the fragment, and disable the whole view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

In my **main.xml** layout, I have an `<FrameLayout>` element which is the **fragment placeholder**:

**main.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I add Fragment **programmatically** to the above `<FrameLayout>` by:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment, null);
```

I can then use the `replace()` to change to other fragment:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, otherFragment, null);
```

At some point of my project, I need to **get the current showing fragment**, and **disable** everything on the view. I firstly successfully get the current showing fragment by :

```
Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_placeholder);
```

Then, **how can I disable the view of the fragment ?** On the view, there could be buttons, is it possible to disable the whole view? If it is not possible, how can I add an overlay on the view?

**I tried:**

```
currentFragment.getView().setEnabled(false);
```

But, it does not work, I can still click on buttons on the view.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068873/how-can-i-disable-all-views-inside-the-layout

Answer (score 9):

As per @Georgy's comment, here is a copy of the answer from [Disable the touch events for all the views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8849672/383414) (credit to [@peceps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590531/peceps)).

---

Here is a function for disabling all child views of some view group:

```
 /**
   * Enables/Disables all child views in a view group.
   * 
   * @param viewGroup the view group
   * @param enabled <code>true</code> to enable, <code>false</code> to disable
   * the views.
   */
  public static void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
      view.setEnabled(enabled);
      if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
      }
    }
  }
```

---

You can call this passing in your `Fragment`'s view as retrieved by `Fragment.getView()`. Assuming that your fragment's view is a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Downside of this solution is that when a view is already disabled when disabling all views, it will be enabled when enabling all views. The function could return a (weak) list of all views that were disabled, so you can enable that list again, instead of enabling everything.

Comment: @Marcel absolutely agree it could be improved upon. But 4 years after posting, neither this, nor the original answer, have been improved on. If you'd like to provide an update along the lines you suggest, I'll be happy to vote it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Kotlin implementation with @Marcel's suggestion.

```
fun ViewGroup.enableDisableViewGroup(enabled: Boolean, affectedViews: MutableList<View>) {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val view = getChildAt(i)
        if (view.isEnabled != enabled) {
            view.isEnabled = enabled
            affectedViews.add(view)
        }

        (view as? ViewGroup)?.enableDisableViewGroup(enabled, affectedViews)
    }
}

fun MutableList<View>.restoreStateAndClear(enabled: Boolean) {
    forEach { view -> view.isEnabled = enabled }
    clear()
}
```