# Android equivalent of iOS's beginIgnoringInteractionEvents

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13833692/1073131) SO answer suggest to iterate through the childviews and disable them. It doesn't smell right to me (performance wise)

What's the best approach to <strike>disable ALL touch events in the application</strike> prevent the user from interacting with the application (during an animation, let's say)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [how we solved this](https://github.com/Widgetlabs/fleet/blob/master/fleet/ui/src/main/java/eu/widgetlabs/fleet/ui/FleetActivity.java) by overriding the `dispatch` methods in `Activity`.

Comment: Great approach, Thanks!