# Is it possible to show the preview of the activity in another activity as a scrollable preview?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a long scroll view where it contains Text views,edit texts,radio buttons,check boxes,Sliders etc..
I want to show the preview of the scroll view and the contents whatever the user had entered and which should be non editable.
Is there any possibility in android that we can do this?.

I have two suggestions
1.Disabling the scroll view from entering inputs and
2.Showing the preview of the scroll view.

is there any possibilities of these two or else some other methods to achieve this in android.

need help, thanks in advance..

Comment: Would a screenshot do?

Comment: @Skynet...the preview should be scrollable..

Comment: When user complete input and take next action just try to disable input using editable false.

Comment: i just want to show the preview of the whole scroll view on a single button click.

Comment: A screenshot cant be scrollable, it will be only that part which is visible on the screen. Instead you can do what Haresh has suggested. If you want to decrease the size, theme it as a Dialog. Also instead of disabling all of your views let the parent layout consume your clicks.

Comment: @HareshChhelana...that is what i am looking for...will check and let u know

Comment: @Skynet...yes thanks,ill check that.

Answer (score 0):

This method helped to disable the views.

```
private static void setViewAndChildrenEnabled(View view, boolean enabled) {
view.setEnabled(enabled);
if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        setViewAndChildrenEnabled(child, enabled);
    }
}
```

}

hope this will help some one else.[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068873/how-can-i-disable-all-views-inside-the-layout)