# Android EditText setEnabled vs setFocusable

Tags: android

When attempting to save info to a server, I disable EditTexts (odds are the user can't change the info, but better safe than sorry).

In order to prevent the user from using the EditTexts, I can use either `setEnabled(false)` or `setFocusable(false)`. In order to start using the EditTexts again, I call `setEnabled(true)` or `setFocusable(true); setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`.

I'm guessing using `setEnabled` is more efficient because there are less method calls, but is this the case (basically, I'd like to know which method is more efficient)?

Or are there other side-effects of using one vs the other that I don't know about?

#### Edit - Solution

In order to prevent myself from needing to `setEnable(true/false)` to multiple different `Views` in multiple different `Fragments`, I implemented the following code (I took the idea from another [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068873/how-can-i-disable-all-views-inside-the-layout)):

```
public static void setViewAndChildrenEnabled(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);

    if(view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            setViewAndChildrenEnabled(child, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

I put this in my `Utils` package so any `Activity/Fragment` can call it. It works pretty nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to prevent the user from using the EditTexts

I recommend you to use `setEnable()` instead of `setFocusable()` since you see a difference when an `EditText` it's enabled or not, if you don't want to see the difference just use `setFocusable(false)` it will keep the same appearance but you won't be able to modify the value.

> In order to start using the EditTexts again

You can do it calling `setEnabled(true)` (if you used `setFocusable(false)`, you'll have to use `setFocusable(true)`

Let's say something: `setFocusable()` it's used for enable or disable views focus event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setEnabled` to enabled and disable. setFocusable allows the user to tap, same with touch mode, which would be ignored.