# Grascale a Layout

Tags: android, grayscale

I have the below layout at first :

[image: Original]

Later on a particular condition i want to make the layout grayed out like this :

[image: Grayscale]

I tried to add a gray view in front of the layout like this :

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/search_item"/> //this is the original layout
        <View
            android:background="#90000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

but this is not working. anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Simply disable it.

Comment: @Rotwang how do we do it?

Comment: By using `setEnabled(true|false);`

Comment: setEnabled(true|false); on what? on the layout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7069377/2649012

Comment: using `setEnabled` does not make your view (and its child views) draw in grayscale, you have to create a custom `ViewGroup` (`FrameLayout` for example) and override its `draw` / `dispatchDraw` method

Comment: @pskink Not necessarily. You can define a [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) for your Views

Comment: @Rotwang StateListDrawable? what would you do with `SLD`? how would it make a red heart became grey?

Comment: @pskink Did you know? SLD has an [`enabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android:state_enabled) state. Just associate a greyscale drawable to that state.

Comment: @Rotwang the OP has an `ImageView` with a red heart, how will it change a red heart into grey heart? SLD has nothing do with child views drawing

Comment: @pskink The OP is supposed to provide 2 version of the bitmap: colorful and greyscale.

Comment: @Rotwang also two versions of yellow / grey star in the `RatingBar`? also two versions of the avatar on the left (most likely downloaded from the web service)? no, he just want one view and its children to be drawn in grey scale, no matter what is drawn on it

Comment: @pskink Of course. 2 versions of all. This is the fastest way. Rather than calculating a greyscaled version of every bitmap.

Comment: @Rotwang you dont need any second greyscaled versions of your bitmaps, just draw all child views in grayscale (no matter how many / what they are)

Comment: @pskink Then loose CPU time doing your drawings, if you prefer to.

Comment: @Rotwang did you observe dramatic loosing CPU time because of calling `Paint#setColorFilter` ?

Comment: @pskink Maybe not "dramatic" but far from being optimal.

Comment: @Rotwang ok do you know that every `Drawable` color tinting is made by calling `Paint#setColorFilter` ? this is used by every app that calls `Drawable#setTintList(ColorStateList tint)` and nobody suffers since everything is done in a hardware layer

Comment: @pskink but tinting is not swapping a drawable, is it?

Comment: @Rotwang i have no idea what `swapping` you are talking about, run [those](http://pastebin.com/YhWz00d2) 30 lines of code twice: with `GRAYSCALE` set to `true` and `false` and tell me where you see "far from being optimal.` performace loss

Comment: @pskink `swapping` means `changing one thing fo another one`. Drawing takes longer, I guess. Therefore, not an optimal way.

Comment: @Rotwang but what drawable do you want to change into another? what does it have to do with the greyscale painting? did you run the code i posted?

Comment: @pskink I'm not talking of painting. I'm talking of swapping. That's the difference: slower vs faster.

Comment: @Rotwang swapping? so who and where swaps what? the OP wants to paint the view and all its children in grayscale, not swap (whatever it means) anything, he wants to paint

Comment: @pskink Swapping is the way a StateLstDrawable works. Which is the better choice for the OP. Of course, you're free not to get the subtle difference and go on with painting.

Comment: @Rotwang and after replacing some Drawable into another the view doesn't need to be **redrawn** (repainted)? it automagically pops up on the screen without painting?

Comment: @pskink Well that's an internal gear. But I don't force a new one my own.

Comment: I can get the gray image of heart and star but on the left is the profile picture of the user, so i will get it from the webservice, so the issue is to convert it to gray. and the performance is not much of an issue here cause i have to create the view only once. so what do you suggest?

Comment: make your custom `ViewGroup`, like [this](http://pastebin.com/YhWz00d2)

Comment: you can even create stuff like [that](http://pastebin.com/MJsg2bqH), click on the image to see it in action