# Enabled/Disable and Clickable Property is not working in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i want to Enabled/Disable a specific row of RecyclerView so in Adapter Class i implement my Logic in onBindViewHolder function but when i apply the Enabled Property than it doesn't create any effect on my holder item.
So can anyone tell me how it is done.

Note:

1. I know there are many similar questions out there but i tried most of them but it didn't work.
2. Visiblity Property is working on my holder Item

Code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  RegsiteredCarDisplayItem displayItem = displayItems.get(position);

    holder.modelName.setText(displayItem.getMyOwnedCar().getCarModelName());        if(selected_usersList.contains(displayItems.get(position).getMyOwnedCar()))
        holder.childView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.buttonbackground));

    else
        holder.childView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.textViewBackground));

    if (displayItems.get(position).getVisible()){
        Log.d("AIAITRUE", String.valueOf(displayItems.get(position)));
        holder.childView.setEnabled(true);
        holder.childView.setClickable(true);

    }else{
            // here i want to Disable my Holder View but the below line is not working, but i use another property like alpha instaed of Enabled property than property(refrence alpha) is working 
           holder.childView.setEnabled(false);
        }

}
```

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"

  >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icons"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"


    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_five"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_five"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icons"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="false"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/modelNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:drawableTint="@color/buttonbackground"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                tools:targetApi="m"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/registration_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_registration_number"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/left_margin_registration_number"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/next_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:foregroundGravity="right"
            android:tint="@color/buttonbackground"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next"/>



    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

VieHolder Class:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView carName,modelName,registrationNumber; View cardView;
    RelativeLayout childView;ImageView imageView; ImageView imageicon;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),  "fonts/helvetica-neue-ce-55-roman.ttf");
        Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),  "fonts/helvetica-neue-ce-35-thin.ttf");
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        modelName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.modelNumber);
        registrationNumber=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.registration_number);
        childView =(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
        imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.next_icon);
        imageicon=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icons);
        modelName.setTypeface(custom_font);
        registrationNumber.setTypeface(custom_fonts);


    }


}
```

Comment: try it for parent view (here card view)

Comment: oky let me try...

Comment: @BapusahebShinde still same problem

Comment: try it for all individual items may work.

Comment: i m not getting

Comment: for 2 image and 2 textviews

Comment: can u give me the little bit explanation so i can get your point

Comment: holder.modelName.clearFocus();
            holder.modelName.setEnabled(false);
            holder.modelName.setClickable(false);

Comment: I think you are inflating the wrong view. Post your view xml with an id of content_saved_vehicle

Comment: check updated code @Gotiasits

Comment: Can you tidy up your code a bit and share only the crucial part that we need to know?

Comment: sure @azizbekian...

Comment: check my updated code @azizbekian

Comment: When you say "apply the Enabled Property than it doesn't create any effect on my holder item" what do you mean by "doesn't create any effect"? Are you expecting there to be a visual clue about whether the child view is disabled or enabled?

Comment: can you post the viewHolder class that you're using

Comment: please check updated code @IsmailIqbal

Comment: @Cheticamp actualy as per my understanding if any item is disabled than onClick doest create any effect on that itemView but in my case that item is Clickable.

Comment: where is `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: can you add the code for the onchildView Click listener as well as @agiMualana mentioned

Comment: what does enable means

Comment: @AnilShrestha it's means i want to disbaled/enabled (Clickable-Non Clickable with alpha property) a specfic row

Comment: @AgiMaulana i think there is no need to add a `setOnClickListener`.....

Answer (score 4):

Check that you are actually clicking on the view you think you are clicking on. You may be overlaying the view for which you are trying to suppress clicks with another view so, even if you disabled the view you are interested in, you will see clicks from the overlaying view. You can check the id of the view passed into the click handler to check this out.

If this is the case, then setting other attributes such as background color and alpha would still work.

Answer (score 2):

try this for all views:

```
holder.modelName.clearFocus();
            holder.modelName.setEnabled(false);
            holder.modelName.setClickable(false);
//registrationNumber
 holder.registrationNumber.clearFocus();
            registrationNumber.modelName.setEnabled(false);
            registrationNumber.modelName.setClickable(false);
```

also try below  code at end not at start:

```
if (displayItem.getVisible()){
          /*  holder.ll_listitem.setEnabled(true);
            holder.ll_listitem.setClickable(true);*/

        }else{
            Log.d("OnFalse",String.valueOf(displayItem.getVisible()));
           holder.ll_listitem.clearFocus();
            holder.ll_listitem.setEnabled(false);
            holder.ll_listitem.setClickable(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you change the value of `displayItems.get(position).getVisible()`.

Are you sure to call [notifyItemChanged(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) or [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) when the state change ?

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
        holder.childView.setEnabled(false);
        holder.childView.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the view for which you have called **setEnabled(false)** is actually getting disabled but you are clicking on any of the child views, which are still enabled. To disable those views, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068873/how-can-i-disable-all-views-inside-the-layout) question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some little changes,
You can put one extra layout of gray color on top of your rowHolder for disable functionality.

For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icons"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linearlayout"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:clickable="false"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icons"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/modelNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                    tools:targetApi="m" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/registration_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/next_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linearlayout"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:foregroundGravity="right"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profle_icon" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rLayoutDisable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#99000000"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Disable"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And Now set visibility of **rLayoutDisable** visible or gone  and remove click event of other layout if you needed.

like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RegsiteredCarDisplayItem displayItem = displayItems.get(position);

        holder.modelName.setText(displayItem.getMyOwnedCar().getCarModelName());
        if (selected_usersList.contains(displayItems.get(position).getMyOwnedCar()))
            holder.childView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.buttonbackground));

        else
            holder.childView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.textViewBackground));

        if (displayItems.get(position).getVisible()) {
            Log.d("AIAITRUE", String.valueOf(displayItems.get(position)));
            holder.rLayoutDisable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.childView.setEnabled(true);
            holder.relativelayout.setEnabled(true);
            holder.childView.setClickable(true);

        } else {
            holder.rLayoutDisable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.relativelayout.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable your click event for a specific row you can add

```
holder.childView.setClickable(false)
```

with respect to position, and also try to debug by putting a break point on it, so that, than you clearly came to know, if your controller is coming/executing that statement or not.

Comment: yeah, but when i debug the code this `holder.childView.setClickable(false)` piece of code is also invoked but still Clickable is working across this row

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable click event for any view in adapter then you need to set click true in your layout file and then in adapter just check that view is clickable. If clickable then set on click listener.