# Android Grey Out LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout which contains a set of child views (mixture of text, images and other layouts).

I want to grey out the linear layout and all the child views so they look disabled (similar to how a button works).

Is this possible to achieve? I know i can set a colour filter when painting on the canvas, is there something similar for layouts?

Comment: can't just set background color?

Comment: no, because all the text/child views are layered on top of the background colour. So they won't look disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to call setEnabled() on each child (for example if you want to do some extra check on child before disabling), check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7069377/4840812

Comment: I tried this but some of the child views don't automatically "grey" themselves.

Comment: @MichaelEdwards try improved solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/49364466/4840812

Answer (score 0):

You can use Frame-layout

Using **TEST ONE** you can achieve above text view like disabled. You can set root layout clickable false for actually disable views inside layout. 
**TEST TWO**  is for understanding purpose. Like you need to manage order of view to show effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--THIS IS TEST ONE-->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TEST DATA"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#DAD6D6D6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<!--THIS IS TEST TWO-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:background="#DAD6D6D6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TEST DATA"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your layout you can use the `RelativeLayout`. In RelativeLayout you can use the 2 different views or `LinearLayout`. In first layout you can add views according to your need, and In second layout you can set the alpha colorcode for disable the layout.

Please try below code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/demo_img_1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/demo_img_1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/trans"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is output for code:

[image]